# How to rename a type imported from an external crate and disallow the original name?

Tags: rust, import

I want to use the `Vec1` type from https://crates.io/crates/vec1, but I want to rename it to a more descriptive `NonEmptyVec`, and I would like to make sure I only refer to it by that name throughout the project.

I know that I can reexport it with the new name (`pub use vec1::Vec1 as NonEmptyVec`) and refer to that, but is there a way to make sure I don't accidentally import the original type? For example, can I restrict importing from an external crate to a specific module?

Comment: I tried using clippy's "disallowed-types" lint but whether you use a `use` rename or `type` alias, clippy saw `NonEmptyVec` as a use of the underlying type. So that doesn't work.

Comment: I suppose an extreme solution would be to create a new package in the workspace that wraps the dependency and reexports it under the new name, but that seems a little heavy-handed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot.

The closest you can come up with is to have a different package that only it has `vec1` as a dependency and it reexports it under a different name. You can make one package for all name changes you want.